# How to prepare a string with foreign / accented characters for XML in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, string

I would like to transform a string like this

```
"¿Cómo puede hacerse esto?"
```

Into something that can be used within an XML resx file like this:

```
"&#191;C&#243;mo puede hacerse esto?"
```

I have tried `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` and `WebUtility.HtmlEncode` without any success.  I have searched online and can't seem to find the right solution.

I think I may need to put the string into a character array and iterate through each character and work out which one needs to be transformed.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try  to  use [HttpUtility.HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.httputility.htmlencode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  if you  are using an asp.net project  or something like the follwong snippet code if not

```
        string str ="¿Cómo puede hacerse esto?";
        string newMStr = string.Empty; 

        foreach (var ch in str)
        {
            int chCode = Convert.ToInt16(ch); 
            if (chCode>127)
            {
                newMStr += string.Format("&#{0};", chCode);
            }
            else
            {
                newMStr += ch;    
            }


        }


        //Print  NewMstr
```

Comment: Thanks - I have tried the above example but I get an overflow exception on the Convert.ToInt16, when I change it to Convert.Int32 I end up with &#65533; which doesn't seem right.

Comment: can you debug it and show me at wich character  please

Comment: the code works perfectly  for me for the example you have provided

Comment: I have sorted it now - your code is now working fine for me.  I had the detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks set to true (content was coming from CSV file).  Setting this property to false resolved the issue.